# portable cross-platform WebDAV Client

Tags: linux, portable, cross-platform, webdav

I am looking for a portable application that will allow me to do this:

Browse a WebDAV share and open a file.
Edit the file locally.
Save the file, and automatically propagate the change to WebDAV.

Is there any CROSS-PLATFORM application out there that will let me do this and exists as a portable?

The reason I need this functionality is that I regularily have to access files via WebDAV from public machines where I do not have the neccessary permissions to natively mount a webdav share, or to install the neccessary components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is [DAV explorer](http://www.davexplorer.org/download.html), it is coded in java so you need the JVM on the systems. Also there's an [online one](http://www.jscape.com/products/file-transfer-clients/anyclient/anyclient-web-service/)(it's java too), not sure about it's trustability.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [CrossFTP Pro](http://www.crossftp.com/), which is a powerful WebDav client supporting the lock/view/edit operation on WebDav site.